# Does sqlcmd.exe have "spyware"?

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I'm just wondering if the `sqlcmd.exe` has client-side Telemetry, CEIP (Customer Experience Improvement Program), or any other form of "spyware" baked into it and turned on by default? And if so how to turn it off?

The following is from SQL Server's license agreement, `license_Std_Linux.txt`

> The software enables Microsoft to collect telemetry by default. You may turn off telemetry at the Server and client levels by following the instructions at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=733886. **There are separate controls to turn off telemetry at the Server level and the client level.**  If you turn off telemetry at the Server level only, **Microsoft will collect telemetry through the client level unless you also turn off telemetry at the client level.**

Comment: I really wonder how come this question has so many downvotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Microsoft claims Telemetry is an SSL-only technology.

- Watching `sqlcmd.exe` with `lsof`, no weird TCP/IP connections.
- It's not linked against openssl or any ssl library.
- It doesn't read the environmental variables which seem to be how other Microsoft client disable telemetry.

That said, the next version of the SQL client, [mssql-cli](https://github.com/dbcli/mssql-cli) does have telemetry that can be turned off by setting `MSSQL_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT=1`

> ### mssql-cli Telemetry
>
> By default, mssql-cli collects usage data in order to improve your experience. The data is anonymous and does not include
>   commandline argument values. The data is collected by Microsoft.
>
> Disable telemetry collection by setting environment variable
>   `MSSQL_CLI_TELEMETRY_OPTOUT` to 'True' or '1'.
>
> Microsoft Privacy statement:
>   https://privacy.microsoft.com/en-us/privacystatement